# Python - default value in class method and <code>self</code>

Tags: python, class, constructor

I have the following class and method:

```
class Basis(object):

 def __init__(self, P = {'dimension': 1, 'generation':1}):

  self.P = P
  self.P['angle'] = np.pi/4
```

where  `P`  is a `dict` that does not include the `'angle'`, hence why I am setting it within the constructor (the angle is something fixed for now, but I might have it a user-defined funciton in the future).

Now I have a method:

```
def make_projection(self, dimension, angle = np.pi/4):
 return (angle*3)
```

and I would like to set the default value of `angle` in this function to the `self.P['angle']` defined in the constructor. 
 I do not want to use the `self.P['angle']` within the main code of the function, as I might use the method on its own giving it a different angle.

If I just do:  `def make_projection(self, dimension, angle = self.P['angle']):` , it underlines both `self` and I do not understand why.

--

Is this something I am allowed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the defaults for keywords arguments in methods can't be mutable objects, like `list`, `dict`, etc. [Here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) you can read why.

Secondly, in `def make_projection(self, dimension, angle = self.P['angle'])` the `self` variable is still not defined, so you can get `self.P` only in method's body.

Try this:

```
class Basis(object):

  def __init__(self, P=None):
    self.P = P or {'dimension': 1, 'generation':1}
    self.P['angle'] = np.pi/4

  def make_projection(self, dimension, angle=None):
    angle = angle if angle is not None else self.P['angle']  # we must compare to None, because angle can be 0.
    return angle*3
```

Comment: well they _can_ be mutable objects, but they _shouldn't_ be due to the implications and counter-intuitive behavior to new-comers who may be expecting different behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Python default values for arguments are evaluated when the function is **defined**, not when the function is **called**.

You need to do something like:

```
def foo(self, x, y=None):
    if y is None:
        y = self.defval
```

This is also the reason for which having a mutable default (e.g. a dictionary) is a dangerous trap in Python; if you change the value that was given by default you're also changing what will be the default in future calls.